# Python equivalent for 'grep -C N'?

Tags: python, regex, unicode

So right now I'm looking for something in a file. I am getting a `value` variable, which is a rather long string, with newlines and so on. Then, I use re.findall(regex, value) to find regex. Regex is rather simple - something like "abc de.*".

Now, I want not only to capture whatever regex has, but also context(exactly like `-C` flag for `grep`).

So, assuming that I dumped `value` to file and ran grep on it, what I'd do is `grep -C N 'abc de .*' valueinfile`

How can I achieve the same thing in Python? I need the answer to work with Unicode regex/text.

Comment: Add sample text and what you want to extract from that?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.deque

Comment: @SIslam text is irrelevant. I want exactly the functionality of `grep -C`. I don't have sample text, I could come up with it, but that's not needed imho, since the tool defines the functionality.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams What about the link?

Comment: Use a deque to store the last *n* lines (once that many lines are present, popleft for each new line added). When your regular expression finds a match, return the previous *n* lines in the stack then iterate *n* more lines and return those also. This keeps you from having to iterate on any line twice (DRY) and stores only minimal data in memory.

Answer (score 2):

My approach is to split the text block into list of lines. Next, iterate through each line and see if there is a match. In case of a match, then gather the context lines (lines that happens before and after the current line) and return it. Here is my code:

```
import re

def grep(pattern, block, context_lines=0):
    lines = block.splitlines()
    for line_number, line in enumerate(lines):
        if re.match(pattern, line):
            lines_with_context = lines[line_number - context_lines:line_number + context_lines + 1]
            yield '\n'.join(lines_with_context)

# Try it out
text_block = """One
Two
Three
abc defg
four
five
six
abc defoobar
seven
eight
abc de"""

pattern = 'abc de.*'

for line in grep(pattern, text_block, context_lines=2):
    print line
    print '---'
```

Output:

```
Two
Three
abc defg
four
five
---
five
six
abc defoobar
seven
eight
---
seven
eight
abc de
---
```

Answer (score 0):

[As recommended](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34045227/python-equivalent-for-grep-c-n#comment55844990_34045227) by [Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams](https://stackoverflow.com/users/20862/ignacio-vazquez-abrams), use [a deque](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.deque) to store the last *n* lines. Once that many lines are present, popleft for each new line added. When your regular expression finds a match, return the previous *n* lines in the stack then iterate *n* more lines and return those also.

This keeps you from having to iterate on any line twice (DRY) and stores only minimal data in memory. You also mentioned the need for Unicode, so handling file encoding and adding the Unicode flag to RegEx searches is important. Also, the other answer uses re.match() instead of re.search() and as such may have unintended consequences.

Below is an example. This example only iterates over every line ONCE in the file, which means context lines that also contain hits don't get looked at again. This may or may not be desirable behavior but can easily be tweaked to highlight or otherwise flag lines with additional hits within context for a previous hit.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import codecs
import re
from collections import deque

def grep(pattern, input_file, context=0, case_sensitivity=True, file_encoding='utf-8'):
    stack = deque()
    hits = []
    lines_remaining = None

    with codecs.open(input_file, mode='rb', encoding=file_encoding) as f:
        for line in f:
            # append next line to stack
            stack.append(line)

            # keep adding context after hit found (without popping off previous lines of context)
            if lines_remaining and lines_remaining > 0:
                continue  # go to next line in file
            elif lines_remaining and lines_remaining == 0:
                hits.append(stack)
                lines_remaining = None
                stack = deque()

            # if stack exceeds needed context, pop leftmost line off stack 
            # (but include current line with possible search hit if applicable)
            if len(stack) > context+1:
                last_line_removed = stack.popleft()

            # search line for pattern
            if case_sensitivity:
                search_object = re.search(pattern, line, re.UNICODE)
            else:
                search_object = re.search(pattern, line, re.IGNORECASE|re.UNICODE)

            if search_object:
                lines_remaining = context

    # in case there is not enough lines left in the file to provide trailing context
    if lines_remaining and len(stack) > 0:
        hits.append(stack)

    # return list of deques containing hits with context
    return hits  # you'll probably want to format the output, this is just an example
```